# How to install missing plug-in wayland-egl

Tags: plugins, wayland

I am installing vokoscreen 3.0.8:

https://snapcraft.io/vokoscreen-ng

When I try to run it, it tells me:

```
wiktor@wiktor:~$ vokoscreen-ng
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How to install the missing wayland-egl?

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on Wayland.

Comment: Try to install the packages - `sudo apt-get install qtwayland5 libwayland-egl-backend-dev` and report back.

Comment: No, it didn't solve my problem. It's the same. I found a way to go past this requirement by typing: ```DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 vokoscreen-ng```, but Vokoscreen doesn't work on Wayland anyway. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Have you tried to use `vokoscreen-ng` [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vokoscreen-ng) instead of Snap?

Comment: deb is 3.0.7. It doesn't complain about the missing plugin, but this version doesn't support Wayland. I wanted to install vokoscreen thru snaps, as these are 3.0.8 and 3.0.9, but they don't support Wayland either. When I want to use vokoscreen, I will probably have to switch to X11. Do you know any screen recorders that support Wayland out of the box?

Comment: I do not know any. I'm using 18.04 LTS with X11 on Intel. Let's wait for answers/comments from other users.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
sudo apt install libwayland-egl++0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-egl1
```

Comment: It doesn't help.